# Remove lines in video

Tags: videos

I am developing a demo website for a client, how do I remove the lines in the videos on this site? [image: link to website www.afritechmedia.com/demo]

ink to website www.afritechmedia.com/demo

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with WordPress, but the line is applied via CSS on `.qt-caption::after`

In your scss file, `_typography.scss` look for:

```
.qt-caption {
    padding: 0.33em 0 0.7em 0;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
    position: relative;
    &::after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        content: " ";
        background: rgba(150,150,150,0.3);
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

And either remove the `::after` block, or set it to `display: none;` instead.